# Prove that there is no irreducible polynomial of degree 2 in $\mathbb C[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> Prove that there is no irreducible polynomial of degree 2 in $\mathbb C[x]$.

I know this result is true from the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, which states that any polynomial in $\mathbb C[x]$ with degree $n\ge 1$, has at least $1$ root in $\mathbb C$.

However, this question is asked in the textbook before the FTA is introduced. How can I go about proving it?

Answer (score 2):

You use the quadratic formula to find the root(s).

Comment: So do I just say the following:

Let $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$, then we know $x_0= \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$ is a root of $f$, that is $f(x_0)=0$. We then have two cases to consider. If $b^2 - 4ac \ge 0$, then $x_0 \in \mathbb R \subset \mathbb C$ and if $b^2 - 4ac < 0$, then $x_0 \in \mathbb C$. Either way, we have found a root of $f(x)$ in $\mathbb C$ and, consequently, $f(x)$ is reducible in $\mathbb C[x]$?

Comment: Almost. You have to deal with $a,b,c\in\mathbb C$, so it is not about the sign of $b^2-4ac$. What you need to show somehow is that any complex number has a square root; then you can use one root of $b^2-4ac$ to find the root of your polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

It's not restrictive to assume the polynomial is monic, write it for simplicity as $x^2+2bx+c$ and consider
$$
x^2+2bx+c=x^2+2bx+b^2+c-b^2=(x+b)^2-(b^2-c)
$$
If you prove that $b^2-c=d^2$, for some $d\in\mathbb{C}$, then
$$
x^2+2bx+c=(x+b)^2-d^2=(x+b-d)(x+b+d)
$$
is not irreducible.

Now the task is to show that any complex number is a square. Consider
$$
A+Bi=(X+Yi)^2
$$
with $A,B$ given real numbers and $X,Y$ unknown real numbers. This translates to
$$
\begin{cases}
X^2-Y^2=A \\[4px]
2XY=B
\end{cases}
$$
and we can divide the problem into a few cases.

Case 1: $A=0$, $B=0$. Choose $X=Y=0$.

Case 2: $B=0$, $A>0$. Choose $X=\sqrt{A}$ or $X=-\sqrt{A}$ and $Y=0$.

Case 3: $B=0$, $A<0$. Choose $X=0$ and $Y=\sqrt{-A}$ or $Y=-\sqrt{-A}$.

Case 4: $B\ne0$. Rewrite the second equation as $Y=B/(2X)$ and substitute in the first one to get
$$
X^2-\frac{B^2}{4X^2}=A
$$
that becomes
$$
4X^4-4AX^2-B^2=0
$$
which is a biquadratic; this gives
$$
X^2=\frac{A+\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}{2}>0
$$
which has two solutions, from which we can get the corresponding values of $Y$.

---

Side note. Every algebra based proof of the FTA relies on the fact that every complex number is a square (equivalent to no polynomial of degree $2$ being irreducible) and on the weak form of the intermediate value theorem that odd degree polynomials with real coefficients have a root.

Comment: @user26857 Well, algebraic proofs. `;-)`